# How to open a new page using sessionid and response object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing, cookies

I have a situation where a customer logs in my website with credentials. With that credentials I did get the sessionid for another internal website. I am trying to open a website using the sessionid, so that customer don't have to login again to that internal website.

I do have the sessionid and I have stored in a httpcookie like below.

```
 HttpCookie mycookie = new HttpCookie("xyz");
        mycookie.Value = sessionId;
        mycookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(9);
```

How to open website using the sessionid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the cookie to the response:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    HttpCookie mycookie = new HttpCookie("xyz");
    mycookie.Value = sessionId;
    mycookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(9);
    Response.AppendCookie(mycookie);
    ...
}
```

Comment: But where do you specify the website(whose sessionid it has) or url.

Comment: @alice7, I don't understand your question. What website url? You need to fetch the cookie value from a remote website?

Comment: If I m understanding right, append the cookie to the response object. and when I will call response.redirect("internal website"); It will open website and automatically logs the user in.

Comment: @alice7, yes, it will log the user if the cookie that you set in the response is valid for this internal site.

Comment: Hi Darin, it is opening the website on the same page, DO you know how to open in a new page?